# While updating mongo collection how to keep collection and DB as parameter?

Tags: python, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, pymongo

How to make db and collection as parameter in updateMany?

```
db.collection.updateMany()
```

I am using python

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that while setting up the connection using the driver,

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/') //this is the url of account
db = client.test_database //setting the db
collection = db.test_collection //setting the collection
```